# Jersey: How to use a custom `ExceptionMapperFactory`

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I need to use a custom `ExceptionMapperFactory` to implement a custom `find()` logic.

```
public class MyExceptionMapperFactory extends ExceptionMapperFactory {

    // [...]

    @Override
    public <T extends Throwable> ExceptionMapper<T> find(Class<T> type) {
         // [...]
    }
}
```

How can I use/register it?

Registering it in my RestApplication has no effect:

```
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public RestApplication() {
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
        register(JacksonXMLProvider.class);

        register(MyExceptionMapperFactory.class);
        register(SomeExceptionMapper.class, 600);
        register(OtherExceptionMapper.class, 550);

        // [...]
     }
}
```

Any ideas? TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never implemented this, so I don't know all the nuances, but briefly looking at the [source](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.24.1/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/ExceptionMapperFactory.java) and the [tests](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.24.1/core-common/src/test/java/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/ExceptionMapperFactoryTest.java), it looks like you just need to [hook it up to the DI system](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.24.1/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/ExceptionMapperFactory.java#L89)

```
register(new AbstractBinder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bindAsContract(MyExceptionMapperFactory.class)
                .to(ExceptionMappers.class)
                .in(Singleton.class);
    }
})
```

Not sure how to disable the original one, but if it is still being used, you can try to [set a rank](https://hk2.java.net/hk2-api/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/ServiceBindingBuilder.html#ranked(int)) for your factory so that when it's looked up, yours will take precedence

```
bindAsContract(MyExceptionMapperFactory.class)
        .to(ExceptionMappers.class)
        .ranked(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        .in(Singleton.class);
```

---

### UPDATE

It seems the following will remove the original factory, since the ranking doesn't work

```
@Provider
public class ExceptionMapperFactoryFeature implements Feature {

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        final ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorProvider.getServiceLocator(context);
        final Descriptor<?> descriptor = locator.getBestDescriptor(new Filter() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(Descriptor d) {
                return d.getImplementation().equals(ExceptionMapperFactory.class.getName());
            } 
        });
        ServiceLocatorUtilities.removeOneDescriptor(locator, descriptor);

        context.register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bindAsContract(MyExceptionMapperFactory.class)
                        .to(ExceptionMappers.class)
                        .in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it does not work. The new one is completely ignored, even if i set a rank of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Try min-value? Maybe I have it wrong. If that doesn't work, I will probably need to test it out later

Comment: It is the same with Integer.MIN_VALUE. It is still ignored.

Comment: Try something like [this](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/bd140e07548babfb96133adf32a6b7a9) to remove it. There may be errors. I'm too lazy to open my IDE. You will need to register the feature. Let me know if that does anything.