# Jersey Client 3.x on Android

Tags: java, android, rest, android-studio, jersey-client

I'm trying to dev a sdk with Jersey 3.0 REST Client on Android Studio and have encountered some problems during the build of sources.

The same sdk ported from desk version working good and is dev using vscode and Maven with JDK 1.8.

This is my gradle.build file and for import a maven artifacts i have added a mavenCentral() in the repositories{}:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jersey_v01"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.md'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.md'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.markdown'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    //implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-cdi2-se:3.0.0-M6'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:3.0.0-M6'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:3.0.0-M6'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:3.0.0-M6'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.0.pr3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Before this last build i have added in this file a Multidex support and excluded the META-INF.

The code of Activity is very simple:

```
package com.example.jersey_v01;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartWriter;

import jakarta.ws.rs.client.Client;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Form;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String serviceUri = "http://address/service";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startClient();

    }

    public void startClient(){

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient()
                .register(MessageBodyWriter.class) // tryed to add for resolve a build error
                                                   // but still not working.
                .register(MultiPartWriter.class);
        WebTarget target = client.target(serviceUri);
        WebTarget endpoint = target
                .path("/auth/authenticate");

        Form form = new Form();
        form.param("email", "mail");
        form.param("password", "pw");

        try {
            Response response = endpoint
                    .request()
                    .post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
            System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The console log:

```
11/21 11:50:53: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 26.
Install successfully finished in 1 s 706 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.jersey_v01/com.example.jersey_v01.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.jersey_v01.test | com.example.jersey_v01
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.jersey_v01.test | com.example.jersey_v01
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.jersey_v01.test | com.example.jersey_v01
Connecting to com.example.jersey_v01
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:44203', transport: 'socket'
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.jersey_v01 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/zygote: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
    waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10086(u0_a86) com.example.jersey_v01 identical 6 lines
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1317)
I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
    Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
I/zygote: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2678)
        at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)

        ....
        ....
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.jersey_v01-k0ai8VmmoQ4FVaZJrxkn0g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.jersey_v01-k0ai8VmmoQ4FVaZJrxkn0g==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
     ...
     ...
        at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2678)
        at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
    ...
    ...
        at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.jersey_v01-k0ai8VmmoQ4FVaZJrxkn0g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.jersey_v01-k0ai8VmmoQ4FVaZJrxkn0g==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2678)
I/zygote:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
        ...
        ...
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2678)
        at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        ...
        ...
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.jersey_v01-k0ai8VmmoQ4FVaZJrxkn0g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.jersey_v01-k0ai8VmmoQ4FVaZJrxkn0g==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
     ...
     ...
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=20KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=20KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
W/MessagingBinders: A class java.awt.image.RenderedImage for a default provider MessageBodyWriter<java.awt.image.RenderedImage> was not found. The provider is not available.
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WELD-ENV-000016: Missing beans.xml file in META-INF
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:773)
W/System.err:     at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:176)
W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.cdi.se.CdiSeInjectionManager.completeRegistration(CdiSeInjectionManager.java:241)
W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:449)
W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.lambda$d1oxBBJfVlzW1xZThvyU0tJbmNM(Unknown Source:0)
W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.-$$Lambda$ClientConfig$State$d1oxBBJfVlzW1xZThvyU0tJbmNM.get(Unknown Source:2)
W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:317)
W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:807)
W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getClientRuntime(ClientRequest.java:219)
W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getInjectionManager(ClientRequest.java:610)
W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.onBuilder(JerseyWebTarget.java:364)
W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:192)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:36)
W/System.err:     at com.example.jersey_v01.MainActivity.startClient(MainActivity.java:45)
        at com.example.jersey_v01.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:44203', transport: 'socket'
```

I have investigate on "beans.xml not found" and i have tried to add it without a positive result. And about missing class java.awt.image: this is not supported ( awt ) on android.

There is some workaround to skip this errors? I have done some researches about a compatibility
of jersey on android and it seem compatible: [oracle blog](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiOjteaz5PtAhWB26QKHf1ECrwQFjAAegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblogs.oracle.com%2Fjapod%2Fjersey-2x-client-on-android&usg=AOvVaw3_dcXSpWAf3nweJEa6mLof)

Comment: Android removed the Java classes that are used to create desktop applications. This includes classes from the awt and swing packages. Jersey has a MessageBodyWriter for `java.awt.image.RenderedImage` and the error message is tellin you that this classes in not found.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but [this is the provider](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/8dcbaf4b5cb0fb345eb949acfa66b1fbe09d1ffb/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/RenderedImageProvider.java) and you can _try_ to remove it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40807190/2587435) in the feature update. I think the missing class should not cause a failure though. At the end of the message it says that the provider is not available. That tells me its more of a warning message.

Comment: For the weld problem, try to use jersey-hk2 instead of the CDI. Otherwise you could try to add a beans.xml file in META-INF